# Transfer backed up iphone data to android phone. is it possible?

Tags: backup

My iphone recently won't charge and it is dead. However, I have managed to backed up the data through itunes sync before the incident. Now I want to get a new android phone. But can I transfer the backed up data to android phone directly?
(I can't turn on my iphone anymore.)

Comment: These articles shows,how to transfer your contacts, calendar, images,mails etc  1.http://www.greenbot.com/article/2937339/smartphones/how-to-switch-from-iphone-to-android-and-keep-all-your-stuff.html 2.http://www.androidauthority.com/how-to-transfer-from-iphone-to-android-ultimate-guide-363230/ 3.https://www.android.com/switch/

Comment: Did you even read my questions? My iphone is dead. I can't turn it on anymore. All I have is the backed up file in my computer. None of the above 'guide' works in this situation.

Comment: A backup created by an iPhone might not be readable/understandable by an Android phone afaik.

Answer (score 0):

Android will certainly not be able to read anything from your backup. However, there are programs specifically designed to extract data from a itunes backup and copy them to an android phone.

[This](http://www.recover-iphone-ios-8.com/transfer-itunes-android.html) is one of those programs.